# Text in Textbox on Different Layer and Different Frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, layer

I'm new to programming; especially object-oriented programming, and have been working on this for a while now.

I have a .fla file; frame 1 is the container.  If you click into it, three more frames show (layer 1).  Frame 2 of layer 1 is the correct animation; frame 3 is the incorrect.  On frame 2 (layer 2, I think) is a dynamic textField.  This is where I want my _correctText to go (_incorrectText needs to go on frame 3 (layer 2).  NOTE:  I have been able to add the text dynamically but I need an actual textbox that our graphic artists can "touch" so that technique was a no-go.

I feel like I need to "bubble up", add listeners, and do displays but I can't figure out how to implement that.

No code can live on the timeline; the idea is to "componentize" this; hence, the inspectables.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you can "dumb down" the terminology, that would be awesome...

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.FrameLabel;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.text.*

public dynamic class hotSpotContainer extends MovieClip
    {   
        var _incorrectText:String = ""; 
        var _correctText:String = "";

        public function hotSpotContainer()
        {
            stop();
            addEventListener (Event.EXIT_FRAME, onExitFrame);
        }

        protected function onExitFrame($event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onExitFrame);
            ButtonClicks();
        }

        public function ButtonClicks()
        /*If the mouse is clicked on one of the buttons listed below, go to the appropriate function.*/
        {
            (this as MovieClip).correct_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, correctAnimation);
            (this as MovieClip).incorrect_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incorrectAnimation);
        }

        public function correctAnimation($event:MouseEvent)
        /*If the correct_Btn is clicked, go to the correctScreen frame and stop.  
        The correctScreen frame includes the correct animation (Correct_anim) which tweens to a correct screen.*/
        {
            gotoAndStop("correctScreen");
            (this as MovieClip).reset_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetImage);
        }

        public function incorrectAnimation($event:MouseEvent)
        /*If the incorrect_Btn is clicked, go to the incorrectScreen frame and stop.  
        The incorrectScreen frame includes the incorrect animiation (Incorrect_anim) which tweens to an incorrect screen.*/
        {
            gotoAndStop("incorrectScreen");
            (this as MovieClip).reset_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetImage);           
        }

        public function resetImage($event:MouseEvent)
        /*If the reset_Btn is clicked, go to the startPoint frame and stop.  
        The startPoint frame brings the user back to the beginning.  Reinvoking ButtonClicks allows the user to start over.*/
        {
            gotoAndStop("startPoint");
            ButtonClicks();
        }

        [Inspectable(name = "01) Incorrect Message Text: ", type = "String", defaultValue = "")]
        /*Creates a parameter field in which to type the incorrect answer message.*/

        public function set incorrectTextBox ($value:String):void
        /*Puts the incorrect answer message in the incorrect text box.*/
        {
            _incorrectText = $value;
        }

        [Inspectable(name = "02) Correct Message Text: ", type = "String", defaultValue = "")]
        /*Creates a parameter field in which to type the correct answer message.*/

        public function set correctTextBox ($value:String):void
        /*Puts the correct answer message in the correct text box.*/
        {
            _correctText = $value;
//          correctTxtBox.text = _correctText
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.FrameLabel;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.text.*
public class hotSpotContainer extends MovieClip
{   
    var _incorrectText:String = ""; 
    var _correctText:String = "";

    public function hotSpotContainer()
    {
        stop();

        addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onExitFrame);
    }

    protected function onExitFrame($event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onExitFrame);
        ButtonClicks();
    }

    /*If the mouse is clicked on one of the buttons listed below, go to the appropriate function.*/

    protected function ButtonClicks() 
    {
        (this as MovieClip).correct_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, correctAnimation);
        (this as MovieClip).incorrect_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incorrectAnimation);
    }

    /* If the correct_Btn is clicked, go to the correctScreen frame and stop.
    The correctScreen frame includes the correct animation (Correct_anim) which tweens to a correct screen.*/

    public function correctAnimation($event:MouseEvent)
    {
        gotoAndStop("correctScreen");

        (this as MovieClip).correct_mc.setResponseText(_correctText);

        (this as MovieClip).response_txt.text = _correctText;

        (this as MovieClip).reset_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetImage);
    }

    /* If the incorrect_Btn is clicked, go to the incorrectScreen frame and stop.  
    The incorrectScreen frame includes the incorrect animiation (Incorrect_anim) which tweens to an incorrect screen.*/

    public function incorrectAnimation($event:MouseEvent)
    {
        gotoAndStop("incorrectScreen");

        (this as MovieClip).incorrect_mc.setResponseText(_incorrectText);

        (this as MovieClip).response_txt.text = _incorrectText;

        (this as MovieClip).reset_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetImage);
    }

    /*If the reset_Btn is clicked, go to the startPoint frame and stop.  
    The startPoint frame brings the user back to the beginning.  Reinvoking ButtonClicks allows the user to start over.*/

    public function resetImage($event:MouseEvent)
    {
        gotoAndStop("startPoint");
        ButtonClicks();
    }

    [Inspectable(name = "01) Incorrect Message Text: ", type = "String", defaultValue = "")]
    public function set incorrectTextBox ($value:String):void
    {
        _incorrectText = $value;
    }

    [Inspectable(name = "02) Correct Message Text: ", type = "String", defaultValue = "")]      
    public function set correctTextBox ($value:String):void
    {
        _correctText = $value;
    }
}
```

}

And, the other class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


public class ResponseAnimation extends MovieClip
{
    protected var _responseText:String = "";

    public function ResponseAnimation()
    {

    }

    public function setResponseText($value:String):void
    {

        var response:String = $value;

        (this as MovieClip).beginning_mc.response_txt.multiline = true;
        (this as MovieClip).beginning_mc.response_txt.wordWrap = true;
        (this as MovieClip).beginning_mc.response_txt.text = response;

        this.visible = true;

    }

}
}
```